# PHP RAW INI parser fails to parse values correctly

Tags: php, parsing, ini

INI data looks like this:

```
[datasources]
live.dsn   = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main"
live.user  = "root"
live.pass  =
```

I'm using [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

- with `INI_SCANNER_RAW` `live.dsn` is parsed incorrectly (`"mysql:host`)
- with `INI_SCANNER_NORMAL` the value of `live.dsn` is correct

But I can't use `INI_SCANNER_NORMAL` because then it will also replace constants, "on" with `1` and so on (don't want that)... Is there any fix or do I have to create my own parser?

I'm using PHP 5.3.

Comment: Please add your PHP version in the question.

Comment: I meant inside the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump(parse_ini_string('[datasources]
live.dsn   = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main"
live.user  = "root"', false, INI_SCANNER_RAW));
```

=>

```
array(2) {
  ["live.dsn"]=>
  string(32) "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main"
  ["live.user"]=>
  string(4) "root"
}
```

I am unable to reproduce it. (It also doesn't work for `parse_ini_file`.) It works in PHP 5.3 and PHP trunk...

---

I see that this was a bug in older PHP versions, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51094 . Simply upgrade, then it should work. If you're unable to upgrade, you really have to write your own ini parser.

Comment: @OneTrickPony Ok, then it was a bug... Updated my answer. (I have PHP 5.3.15, the first version which works xD)

Comment: Ended up using something like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php#94192). Probably slower, but it seems I have no choice :(